# SQL Server : how to cancel a query which is running?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am testing some joins and I queried some large tables. I couldn't stop the query and I just closed the window. Upon closing I was being asked `would you like to close the query`, to which I said yes. Then I restarted the SQL Server Management Studio.

The problem is, from what I read on the internet, the query is still running even if I canceled it. I cannot restart the server and my permissions are limited.

I used `sp_who2 'active'` and then found the active query and tried to kill it with: `kill 84` (the spid of my query). It returned:

> Msg 6102, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   User does not have permission to use the KILL statement.

Then I tried this query for which I also don't have permission:

```
SELECT TOP 20
    qs.sql_handle,
    qs.execution_count,
    qs.total_worker_time AS Total_CPU,
    total_CPU_inSeconds = --Converted from microseconds
        qs.total_worker_time/1000000,
    average_CPU_inSeconds = --Converted from microseconds
        (qs.total_worker_time/1000000) / qs.execution_count,
    qs.total_elapsed_time,
    total_elapsed_time_inSeconds = --Converted from microseconds
        qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000,
   st.text,
   qp.query_plan
FROM
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats as qs
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) as st
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_exec_query_plan (qs.plan_handle) as qp
ORDER BY 
    qs.total_worker_time desc
```

The next stop was using these 2 queries which work and return the following:

```
select * from master..sysprocesses
where status = 'runnable' --comment this out
order by CPU
desc

select * from master..sysprocesses
order by CPU
desc
```

returns:
[image]

What can I do now with the limitations which I have? I would like to avoid the option to 'just let it run' because I don't know how long it will take and I don't want to slow down the performance.

Any advice is well received. Thank you (sql server 2012)

Comment: regarding the vote to close it. Is my question not clear and somehow I can improve it? Am I asking it in the wrong place? Thank you

Comment: The votes to close it are for migrating it to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Then should I copy paste my question there?

Comment: as per the info shared,it seems you dont have permissions to kill the query.Further from the screenshot shared,query is not using much resources.kill requires database connection permission ,i am not sure why you are getting error,try kill <<spid>> with statusonly to see rollback completion percentage of the query if it is rolling back

Comment: use sys.dm_exec_query_requests instead of query_stats to see query status

Comment: @TheGameiswar thank you! So should I try `kill <<84>>` ? Don't know the syntax. Tried `kill 84`.

Comment: yep first try kill 84 and then see kill 84 with statusonly to see rollback status if any

Comment: if i do `kill 84 with statusonly` i get:  `User does not have permission to use the KILL statement.`

Answer (score -1):

For the faster execution, you can press **Alt+ Break** from your keyboard to cancel a long running query. See here for more options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833250(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: on the fist line i wrote `. I couldn't stop the query and I just closed the window. Upon closing I was being asked would you like to close the query, to which I said yes.'` . By `stop the query` I am pointing to the red button called `cancel query` which is the same as `alt+break`. Thank you for taking the time to replay though

Comment: the question is: What to do when when alt + break doesn't work, you can't restart the server and you don't have permission to kill the spid?

Answer (score -2):

if its still running get the DBA to kill it for you

Comment: you do not belong here.